# Trouble with visual studio changing file format when publishing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, xna

I'm building a game with XNA and I'm using custom files, that are really just text files, to store map data. However, when I publish, Visual Studio adds ".deploy" to all my files.

I'm hoping there is an easy way to just have the installer copy the files instead of modifying the file extensions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on my phone so I'm unable to grab a screenshot for you, but you might want to disable the option that adds that file extension.  From the docs:

ClickOnce publishes every application file with a ".deploy" file extension by default. ....
... you can disable this option by clearing the Use ".deploy" file extension option on the Publish Options Dialog Box, in which case you must configure the Web server to unblock all file extensions used in the application.

From:
Server and Client Configuration Issues in ClickOnce Deployments
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228998.aspx

Comment: If it solves the problem make sure to come back and mark the answer as correct so others can benefit from your question :)

Comment: Unfortunately I was wrong about why my project was crashing, I've got the files coping and in the correct format but it still crashes :( Sorry I wasted anyone's time with the wrong question.

Comment: If the answer I provided fixed the problem of the file format, then it answers *that* question, which means others will benefot from you marking an answer. If you still have *other* problems, make a new question with new information. SO is a question and answer forum, not debug sessions.